# How do I make Stripe email a customer who changes their subscription?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe's Python library to process subscriptions.

Here's a snippet of my backend Django code.

```
    susbcriptionID = stripe.Subscription.retrieve("subID")
    stripe.Subscription.modify(
        susbcriptionID,
        items=[{
            "id": subscription["items"]["data"][0].id,
            "plan": "planID",
        }]
    )
```

The [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts) states that Stripe emails customers upon successful charges.

But I tested this out in live mode by having two subscription choices, one for 50 cents a day and the other for 51. When I signed up for the first choice, I inputted my email, and Stripe emailed me a receipt. But when I later switched to the more expensive plan, I got no email.

When I check my Stripe dashboard, I go to Billing > Subscriptions. I click myself under the "Customer" column. When I scroll to "Events," it shows this (I made this pipe-delimited format for easier reading):

```
my@email.com upgraded to Daily test 2 from Daily test | 2018/04/16 20:02:25
A proration adjustment for $0.51 USD was created for my@email.com | 2018/04/16 20:02:25
A proration adjustment for ($0.50 USD) was created for my@email.com | 2018/04/16 20:02:25
my@email.com subscribed to the Daily test plan | 2018/04/16 19:59:53
my@email.com's invoice for $0.50 USD was paid | 2018/04/16 19:59:53
my@email.com has a new invoice for $0.50 USD | 2018/04/16 19:59:53
```

How do I set up Stripe to email a customer when they change their subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe only emails customers after a successful charge as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/dashboard/receipts). In your example though there's no charge so there's no email being sent to the customer.

When you change the plan on a subscription but keep the same billing cycle, Stripe calculates the proration for you. Those proration items are not charged immediately. Instead, they are added as pending invoice items and will be billed on the next invoice when the subscription renews. This is documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/upgrading-downgrading).

If you want to charge the customer for the proration, you have to create an invoice via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoice) and then pay it via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#pay_invoice).

When you do this, then a charge would be created and an email receipt would be sent for the price difference. If the amount is too small (one cent in your case) though there's no charge as it's below the [minimum](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts) that Stripe can charge and it would still be added to their upcoming invoice.

Comment: So in my case I’d need the amounts to be 50 cents and a dollar for Stripe to email an invoice after the subscription change?